# "No such file or directory" when files are in the same directory

Tags: python, working-directory

Both files, the .py file and a .txt file it calls with

```
champions_list = open('champions.txt','rU').read().split('\n')
```

are in the file folder `C:\Users\[My Name]\Programming\[file name]`.

I'm calling the .py file through Command prompt and it returns the error

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: champions.txt
```

Has this happened to anyone else before?

Comment: What's so strange? `open('file.txt')` looks for a file in the current directory, not in the script directory.

Comment: You sure you didn't misspell the file name? Make sure their are no discrepancies.

Comment: Restarted my computer and it worked. No idea what was up...

Answer (score 4):

When you open a file with `open('champions.txt')`, then the OS expects to find the `champions.txt` file in the *current directory*. The current directory is the directory of the command prompt window where you started the program. This is not (necessarily) the same as the directory where the Python script is stored.

You may be able to fix this by doing:

```
import os
import sys

open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'champions.txt')
```

This takes the full name of the script in `sys.argv[0]`, takes the directory part, and then joins that to the file name you want. This will open the file in the script directory, not the current directory.

(Note that using `sys.argv[0]` in this way is OS-dependent, and works on Windows but may not work the same way on other systems.)

Comment: I think it is better to use `__file__` instead of `sys.argv[0]` because `sys.argv[0]` can be relative

Comment: @Elisha: Sure, but it will be relative to the current directory anyway, which is what the OP would need to find the data file.

Comment: It's better to wrap `sys.argv[0]` in `os.path.abspath`

Comment: right, but it still can be problematic when the user run a different script with run this script. if you want it to be relative to the file and not to the way the user run it, I think `__file__` is better

Answer (score 0):

Just because the file is in the same folder **as the script** does not mean the python interpreter knows that the file is there. It is looking for a file in the `cwd`. You can:

- Try using the full absolute path of the file; or
- Add the directory containing the file using `os.path.append`

Comment: There's no such thing as `os.path.append`. Maybe you meant `sys.path`, but that's only relevant for the *module search path*, it has no effect on `open()`'s working directory whatsoever.